# How to bevel edges evenly

Tags: modeling, bevel

I am using version 2.9. I am trying bevel edges evenly, but they don't look right.
Any suggestion, please? Thanks in advance.

[image]

EDIT
I just checked x, y, z scales in transform settings. When I right-click any scale, the menu pops up. Should I choose "Reset All to Default Values" or "Reset Single to Default Value"?
[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe you simply didn't apply the scale of your object?

Comment: @moonboots, probably not. I can't remember exactly what I did in Blender last week and before that. I forget easily. :(

Comment: @moonboots, I now know what to do. I just go to Object Mode and apply scale. Previously, I didn't know that. Thank you for mentioning it. :)